# How do I list string items in a specific order length order?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hashset

I want my program to read the input one line at a time and write each line to the output if it is not a duplicate of some previous input line. And also that a file with a lot of duplicate lines does not use more memory than what is required for the number of unique lines.

Duplicate lines should be printed the same number of times they occur in the input I have done the half of the question but still it doesn't work properly..

```
public class Part1 {




public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    String inpt;
    int n = 0;
    while ((inpt = r.readLine()) != null) {
        s.add(inpt);
        n++;
    }
    Iterator<String> i = s.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        w.println(i.next());
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader r;
        PrintWriter w;
        if (args.length == 0) {
            r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            w = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        } else if (args.length == 1) {
            r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            w = new PrintWriter(System.out);                
        } else {
            r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            w = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        doIt(r, w);
        w.flush();
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Execution time: " + 10e-9 * (stop-start));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work properly".  What is actually going wrong?

Comment: One of the most important steps in solving a problem is determining how to represent the information that your program needs to keep track of.  Specifically, what data structures (usually objects) you want to use in order to do this.  Your use of HashSet will allow you to keep track of each string that your program reads, and check for duplicates.  However it does not give you a way to 'remember' how many times you have seen that string.  Also, a set does not represent any particular 'order' of the elements it stores.

Comment: You can keep your lines as keys and number of occurrence of any line(Frequency) as the value for that particular key.

Answer (score 0):

Your design decision to use a Set is good, but it doesn't help you *count* the occurrences. What you need is s Map. Happily, the keys of a Map are a Set.

Without spoon feeding you the answer:

- Use a `Map<String, Integer>` to store the words and their occurrence total
- Chose `LinkedHashMap` as your Map implementation to preserve order
- Use `Map.contains()` to determine if you need to create a new entry
- Make use of autoboxing/unboxing for arithmetic
- When outputting, iterate over the `Map.entrySet()` using a foreach loop for `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` objects

You should be able to do the whole thing in just a few lines of code.